# Old typographical symbol for Scots pound

Tags: history, typography, money

I came across this typographical symbol in a [book from the late 1800s](https://books.google.com/books?id=RJgxAQAAIAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PA169&dq=%22laurance%20sinclair%20reidare%22&hl=en&source=gb_mobile_entity) that I am digitizing, where it is used as a symbol for the old (pre 1700) Scottish pound. My question - does it have a name? An online search has disclosed nothing.

[image: Scots pound]   [image: Laurance Sinclair reidare at thir Kirkis his Stipend xx li. to be pait be the new providit Vicar.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See how it looks like "li"? It's an abbreviation for *libra*:

> In testaments, sums of money usually appear as abbreviations for pounds, shillings and pence. These abbreviations are normally written superscript (that is, above the other writing in that line of text) in the form:
>
> - *lb* or *li* (with a stroke through it) signifying the Latin word *libra* (meaning pounds);
> - *s* (or double *s*) signifying the Latin word *solidus* (meaning shilling)
> - *d* signifying the Latin word *denarius* (meaning penny).
>
> — [ScotlandsPeople](https://www.scotlandspeople.gov.uk/research-guides/dates-numbers-and-sums-money)

Comment: Does it refer specifically to the old (pre 1700) Scottish pound? Is OP overspecifying its usage?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think you could be right that more than one abbreviation was used throughout the whole Kingdom at the time. After all we often forget the the "pound sign" (£) is a formalised "L" for 'libra" or "livre". I'm not too sure when "£" became universally accepted as the symbol for "pound".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The fact that OP's book was published in the 1800s is a little confusing, but looking at the context I'm pretty sure that it's a faithful replication of what some guy wrote in 1576 (and so the money is in Scottish pounds).

Comment: But does the abbreviation refer specifically (ie solely) to the old (pre 1700) Scottish pound? I think OP is misinterpreting here, and this is just an old variation on the £ sign.